# Sending messages client->server->client on socket.io on node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, node.js

I'm using NodeJS+Socket.IO for simple web game. It works. Why?

Here's my `server.js`

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('set nickname' , function (nickname) {
socket.nickname = nickname;
console.log(nickname + ' just connected!');

});

socket.on('msg' , function (msg) {
socket.msg = msg;
io.sockets.emit('response', msg);
});

socket.on('updatePlayer' , function (updatePlayer) {
console.log("Someone just moved on the map!");
});

});

app.listen(8080);
```

The reason I know it works is because, when I load the page and this script executes:

```
// SERVER STUFF
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('We are connected!');
    name = $(".name").val();
    this.emit('set nickname', name, function (success) {});
    msg = name + "|" + currX + "|" + currY + "|" + currentMap;
    this.emit('msg', msg, function (success) {});

    socket.on('response', function (data) {
        var theMsg = data.split("|");
        sayDialog("New player! " + theMsg[0] + " connected on map " + theMsg[3] + " on coordinates (" + theMsg[1] + "," + theMsg[2] + ")");
    });
});
```

I get in my dialogbox ("CSS div") something like `New player! weka connected on map 4 on coordinates (10,5)`

OK, cool, so it works! However, when I "move" I try sending a message to server using this

```
  socket.on('updatePlayer', function () {
    console.log("Testing...");
  });
```

I don't even see `console` say Testing. I don't know why.

Comment: how are you triggering the `updatePlayer` event ?

Comment: It's not `socket.on('updatePlayer', function () {` but how I don't think I am triggering it... how would I trigger it?

Comment: You have to trigger it from the server to the client: for example this.emit ('updatePlayer', msg); from the server.

Comment: @weka exactly as Wilk has suggested - you need to `emit` the event

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Client-side.** A player moves and the function movePlayer is executed:

```
function movePlayer () {
    socket.emit ('player move', {map: 4, coords: '0.0'});
}

socket.on ('updatePlayer', function (msg) {
    console.log ('A player moves on map ' + msg.map + ' on coords ' + msg.coords);
});
```

**Server-side.** When someone moves, a 'updatePlayer' is emitted for each socket except the original player. On each client side, the updatePlayer is intercepted.

```
socket.on ('player move', function (msg) {
    io.sockets.emit ('updatePlayer', msg);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Server side**

```
socket.on('updatePlayer', function(updatePlayer){
  console.log("Someone just moved on the map!")
  updatePlayer() // will trigger the client side function
});
```

**Client side**

```
socket.emit('updatePlayer', function(){
  console.log('testing');
})
```