# Show user's location to another user on Google Maps

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

My goal is let say if user A toggle the switch

[image]

When it is on, On User B's screen will show the current location of User's A

[image]

and whenever User A is moving to another coordinates, User B could see he is moving something like Uber.

Im using node.js to run the backend and socket.io for real-time communication.

The questions are

1. How do i show current user's location to another user on Google Maps IOS sdk?
2. Do i need any real-time communication to keep updating the position of User A on User B's screen?

Comment: There should be a function to get current location's coordinates, so take that and send it to server and then to user B where you add a marker. Just read the docs it should all be there.

Comment: Do i need to keep updating it using any real-time communication?

Comment: Yes. Don't expect it to magicaly work on its own. Use socket.io and update in reasonable time, every 30sec should be enough

Comment: Check this accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600496/sending-messages-client-server-client-on-socket-io-on-node-js