# SocketIO emit to all clients is not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io, emit

I am trying to get a socketIO server working on NodeJS with Typescript.
The specific behaviour I want create is that it will send a message to all connected sockets (including itself) every 1000ms.

I have the base socket working and when clients connect the 'on connect' message triggers so that is fine.

```
    this.io.on('connection', (socket: Socket)=>{
        console.log('a user connected');
    });
```

So now to emit a message to all clients I have to:

```
        this.io.emit("newTest","Test")
```

Then to listen to this (On the same server directly underneath:)

```
    this.io.on("newTest",(socket:Socket)=>{
        console.log("Echoo")
    })
```

But I don't ever get "echo"  being console logged.
Actually I'm also listening on a client aswell (angular 6 app), and while that app when it connects it correctly displays "a user has connected"...(so the socket is working)... The this.io.emit() doesn't seem to actually send a message.

I CAN send a message if I do:

```
    this.io.on('connection', (socket: Socket)=>{
        console.log('a user connected');

        socket.emit("newTest","test")
    });
```

and that works fine. BUT i can't do this.io.emit().. to emit to all clients. I could manually trying to capture all the "socket" objects in an array as they connect, and then whenever I receive a message I iterate through them and do socket.emit.. but there must be a better way, what am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

To emit a message to all connected clients, you can use `io.sockets.emit` (on the server):

```
io.on('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');

    io.sockets.emit('newTest', 'test');
});
```

See more info on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600926/9155551) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10344883/9155551).

Answer (score 1):

```
 this.io.on("newTest",(socket:Socket)=>{
    console.log("Echoo")
})
```

Is this serverside code?
It must be client side code to listen event sending to all clients.
And for receiving the emitting, you need to do as the follows:

```
socket.on("newTest",(socket:Socket)=>{
    console.log("Echoo")
})
```

This is client side code thoroughly.
Maybe it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it, Problem was on my side.

For the record.
    this.io.emit("testMessage",mesagecontents)

Part of the error was that I thought the server was itself a client.

DOES work.